# Does size of array in C affect time to access or change a piece of data in the array

Tags: c, performance, time

Title says it all:

I create and array, say ARRAY[10000],
I set bounds where I only need to access data from 1-100 and 900-2000.

Will the time to access and/or change a piece of data take a greater amount of time in this manner than if I had declared an array as ARRAY[2001]

Will access and/or change time be changed if I have an array that only has the data from 1-100 and 900-2000?

I have seen some papers on this but they have not been clear to me and was hoping I could get a more concise answer here.

Comment: How is your access pattern?  And why would you even consider creating a huge array only to never even look at 80 % of it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the bounds being set from 1-100 and 900-2000, but the access time doesn't change in array's, you may however be wasting a huge amount of memory

Comment: Unless you pass an array size too large to fit in cache, cause a pipeline stall or make the array small enough to fit in registers I sincerely doubt it.

Comment: If you have a 3 dimensional object and have constraints in the form of a toroid, you only need to access data points in that toroid.  The entire center of your "donut" are never touched.  Without x-y-z coordinates you would have to normalize during each run on the system. @5gon12eder

Comment: @WillFox Why not create an array of [struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)(s) with `x-y-z` coordinates then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the array is accessed infrequently, then the size of the array probably won't make much difference because you'd be getting a cache miss anyway. In that case the time will depend on how quickly the CPU can do any "virtual address to physical address" conversion and fetch the data from RAM.

The more frequently you access something in the array, the more cache effects matter. These cache effects depend heavily on the number, sizes and speeds of different caches.

However, it also depends on your access patterns. For example, if you have a 1 GiB array and frequently access 5 bytes of it, then the size won't make much difference as the 5 bytes you're accessing frequently will be in cache. For another example, if you use a sequential access pattern (e.g. "for each element in array { ... }") then it's likely the CPU might do hardware pre-fetching and you won't pay the full cost of cache misses.

For a typical 80x86 system, with a random access pattern and frequent accesses; there's about 5 different sizes that matter. The first (smallest) is L1 data cache size - if the array fits in the L1 data cache, then it's going to be relatively fast regardless of whether the array is 20 bytes or 20 KiB. The next size is L2 data cache size - as the array gets larger the ratio of "L1 hits to L2 hits" decreases and performance gets worse until (a t maybe "twice as large than L1") the L1 hits become negligible. Then (for some CPUs that do have L3 caches) the same happens with the L3 cache size, where as the array gets larger the ratio of "L2 hits to L3 hits" decreases.

Once you go larger than the largest cache, the ratio of "cache hits to cache misses" decreases.

The next size that can matter is TLB size. Most modern operating systems use paging, and most modern CPUs cache "virtual address to physical address conversions" in something typically called a Translation Look-aside Buffer. If the array is huge then you start getting TLB misses (in addition to cache misses) which makes performance worse (as the CPU can't avoid extra work when converting your virtual address into a physical address).

Finally, the last size that can matter is how much RAM you actually have. If you have a 10 TiB array, 4 GiB of RAM and 20 TiB of swap space; then the OS is going to be swapping data to/from disk and the overhead of disk IO is going to dominate performance.

Of course often you're creating an executable for many different computers (e.g. "64-bit 80x86, ranging from ancient Athlon to modern Haswell"). In that case you can't know most of the details that matter (like cache sizes) and it becomes a compromise between guesses (estimated overhead from cache misses due to "array too large" vs. estimated overhead from other things caused by "array too small").

Comment: This was a very thorough way of stating that it depends, but man was it interesting.  Thank you for taking the time to clarify the hardware components in a very concise and coherent way!

Answer (score 1):

No, at least normally the time to access any item in an array will be constant, regardless of the array's size.

This could change if (for example) you define an array larger than memory, so the OS (assuming you're using one) ends up doing some extra paging to support the larger array. In most cases, even that's unlikely to have much impact though.

Comment: It's not just paging.  That's why I have asked for the access pattern.  If he is iterating over and over again, cache misses will be much more frequently if there are “holes” in the array.

Comment: @5gon12eder I will be iterating over it.

Comment: @WillFox In that case, you should be aware that your hardware will perform best if you are accessing contiguous chunks of memory as that maximizes the percentage of the cache filled with useful data and allows the pre-fetching heuristics to correctly guess what memory you'll need next.  Of course, if you break the array in only two parts and those are relatively large, the penalty should not be too high.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Sorry, but no. Unused "holes" won't create cache misses with most types of caches (unless you actually read the memory you don't care about in the "hole"). It can affect prefetching, but only slightly (and most have predictors, so if you access in a specific pattern repeatedly, they'll detect and follow that).

Comment: If the “holes” are not aligned at multiples of the cache line size, you'll load at least a little garbage into your cache.  And every time you “jump over a hole” it will be hard for the pre-fetching heuristic to guess correctly.  But as I've said in my previous comment, if the contiguous chunks are few and relatively large, it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

May be yes, but it depends on size.

#### cache size

size of access range will change latency.
`int ARRAY[10000]` fit in L1 cache(32KB)
very small size access which fits in L1 cache(32KB), it costs 4 clocks for haswell. 
But L2 cache access costs 12 clocks.

see detail here
http://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Haswell.html

#### cache conflict

it other core of CPU modify some data in array, local cache-line state will be modified to be `Invalid` state.
`Invalid` stated cache-line costs much more latency.

#### NUMA

some environments with multiple CPU sockets on motherboard, it is called as `non-uniform memory access` environment.

That may have huge memory capacity, but some address of memory may be resident in CPU1, other address of memory may be resident in CPU2.

```
int huge_array[SOME_FUGE_SIZE];   // it strides multiple CPU's DIMM
// suppose that entire huge_array is out of cache.
huge_array[ADDRESS_OF_CPU1] = 1;  // maybe fast for CPU1
huge_array[ADDRESS_OF_CPU2] = 1;  // maybe slow for CPU2
```

But I wonder huge array strides multiple CPU's memory.
Allocation of huge array may simply fail.
It depends on OS.

Comment: I really want to select this and Brendan's answer since yours helped make his more easily understood as an intro.  Thanks for the answer, it did really help!

Answer (score 0):

In information *theory*, as was stated by others, array access is constant, and thus does not cost more or less depending on the arrays size. This question seems to be about *real live performance* though, and there the array size definitely matters. How so, is well explained by the accepted answer by @Brendan.

Things to consider in practice:
* How big are the elements of your array: `bool[1000]`, `MyStruct[1000]` and `MyStruct*[1000]` may differ a lot in access performance
* Try writing code for both ways, once using the big array, and once keeping the required data in a smaller array. Then run the code on your target hardware(s), and compare performance. You will often be surprised to see, that optimization attempts make performance worse, and you learn a lot about hardware and its quirks in the process.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it should.

When you access an element, you are going to memory location 0 + (element) therefore, regardless of the size it will get to the same memory location in the same time.